# Difference between Subset and SubGraph

Tags: graph-theory

What is the Difference between Subset of nodes of a graph and a SubGraph of a graph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subset of nodes only contains a set of nodes of the original graph, while a subgraph contains a set of nodes of the original graph as well as a set of edges between these nodes.

Comment: Note this includes distinguishing between a set and a subgraph with no edges - the edge set is the empty set, and structurally the graph is still a pair of sets, the vertex set and the edge set.